# React useEffect & Axios: Making a chained API call in Axios asynchronous

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, axios, use-effect

I'm making multiple API calls to an API. I need to use data from the first call in the following two calls. I'm pulling data from the NHL API to retrieve the first place teams in each conference.

I've done that with this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings/byConference`)
      .then(res => {
        // 0th element is Eastern Conference leader, 1th is Western Conference Leader
        let teamEndpoint = [Object.values(res.data.records).map((x) => x.teamRecords[0].team.link)];

        // Eastern Conference team API endpoint
        let eastern = teamEndpoint[0];

        // Western Conference team API endpoint
        let western = teamEndpoint[1];

        // Get Eastern Conference Leader team's name
        axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com${eastern}/`)
          .then(res => {
            setEasternConferenceLeader(res.data.teams[0].teamName);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error retrieving Eastern Conference Team data : ' + err);
          });
        // Get Eastern Conference Leader team's name
        axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com${western}/`)
        .then(res => {
          setWesternConferenceLeader(res.data.teams[0].teamName);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error retrieving Western Conference Team data : ' + err);
        });
      })
  }, []);
```

The first call retrieves two endpoints. One for an Eastern conference team and one for a Western conference team. After retrieving the two endpoints I want to make two more calls with that data.

The way I am doing this works, but if I `console.log` the data it's initially `undefined`. Later on in my program I'm using the results of these calls to render an image and I'm getting an error. My guess is it's because I'm trying to render the image before the subsequent API calls are done.

How can I make the above code `asynchronous` so I don't have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not about axios call but you not handle for empty data when component initial. You have to check if data isn't retrieved yet, then render something like spin loading until AJAX call finish.

Comment: Ah I didn't consider that. How would I do that with React Hooks? I know you're not supposed to render hooks conditionally.

Comment: It not relate to hooks but in your render function, somethings like this `if (!teamData) { <div>Data loading ...</div> } else { <div>show team data here</div> }`